# XML Query Converting Group by field to child elements

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I want the following query to return the fields in a parent child format. Is this possible?

Here's the query

```
SELECT   Field1,
         Field2,
         Field3
FROM     ATable
GROUP BY Field1,
         Field2,
         Field3
ORDER BY Field1,
         Field2,
         Field3 
FOR xml auto
```

Here's what I would like to get back (doesn't have to be exaxtly like this, I just need the hierarchy.) I cant seem to get the rest of the xml displayed but this is most of it.

```
<Field1 Value='1'>
<Field2 Value='1'>
    <Field3 Value='2'>
</Field2>
<Field2 Value='2'/>
<Field2 Value='3'/>
<Field1/>
<Field1 Value='2'>
<Field2 Value='1'>
    <Field3 Value='2'>
</Field2>
<Field2 Value='2'/>
<Field2 Value='3'/>
<Field1/>
```

Comment: @ty ponies, how do you get it to display correctly?

Comment: you use the "Code Sample" button at the top of the text area. It is the 101010 on two lines. The quote symbol is next to that and it does block quotes. Though you still need to do newlines and spaces in the code to format it otherwise each line starts at the same position. Underneath your answer it previews what you are righting so you can make corrections as you go.

Comment: @Kyra - ty for the feedback. I have been using the 101010 button and pasting into the 'place code here' segment. It seems to goof up on me sometimes though. Who knows.. Thanks!

Comment: I find it easier to type in my code, highlight and then press the button. You don't have to keep pasting it in then. More confusing while typing but with the preview you can fix any problems. And np :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `type` option to nest XML queries.  Here's an example:

```
declare @t table (Field1 int, Field2 int, Field3 int)

insert @t values (1,1,2), (1,2,null), (1, 3, null), 
                 (2,1,2), (2,2,null), (2,3,null)

select  Field1 as 'Field1/@Value'
,       (
        select  Field2 as 'Field2/@Value'
        ,       (
                select  Field3 as 'Field3/@Value'
                from    @t t3
                where   t3.Field1 = t2.Field1
                        and t3.Field2 = t2.Field2
                        and Field3 is not null
                for     xml path(''), type
                ) as 'Field2'
        from    @t t2
        where   t2.Field1 = t1.Field1
                and Field2 is not null
        for     xml path(''), type
        ) as 'Field1'
from    @t t1
group by   
        Field1
for     xml path(''), type
```

-->

```
<Field1 Value="1">
  <Field2 Value="1">
    <Field3 Value="2" />
  </Field2>
  <Field2 Value="2" />
  <Field2 Value="3" />
</Field1>
<Field1 Value="2">
  <Field2 Value="1">
    <Field3 Value="2" />
  </Field2>
  <Field2 Value="2" />
  <Field2 Value="3" />
</Field1>
```

This does tend to get complicated, so instead of generating XML using SQL, consider a client side language like C# or VB.NET instead.

Comment: works great ty! Yeah, I can parse it all out in c# and build the hierarchy (for display in a tree). Thats what I've always done. I wanted to give this a try so I can avoid writing that same-ole convert record to tree function again.

Comment: Excellent! Just what I was looking for.